# Github programming language tag

Tags: r, github

How to add programming language tag in Github repository in direct Github web interface?. I created a repository using R programming language but no tag is found in my repository. What shall I need to do to have R tag? Give me the steps to add language tag in repository using Github web interface.

I'm new to this github. Please help me out to resolve this issue.

Comment: Have you added code to the repository? Have you named the code files with a `.R` extension? How many lines of code are there? Usually the tagging is automatic but there has to be enough information there for github to be able to make a determination.

Comment: You can add tags yourself by clicking on the 'settings' gear-shaped icon next to 'About' in the top right.

Answer (score 0):

If you've uploaded your code as a .rmd file you can add a .gitattributes file to the root folder in your repository and include this

```
*.rmd linguist-language=R
```